# Lie algebra of invariant polynomials or invariant smooth functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, matrices, lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry, invariant-theory

Is there a symplectic structure on  $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$, not  necessarily with  constant  coefficients,   such that the space of smooth  invariant  functions, those smooth functions $f:M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})\to  \mathbb{R}$  with  $f(AB)=f(BA)\;\;\;\; \forall A,B \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$,  would  be closed under the  Poisson bracket ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly a rephrasing of question is requiring a symplectic structure such that the set of commutators $AB-BA$ is contained inside a coisotropic submanifold. It shouldn't be difficult to find a symplectic structure on the space of matrices such that the linear subspace $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ (which contains all commutators, being linearly generated by it) is coisotropic.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Why are commutators related to my question while an invariant polynomial is not necessarily a linear map?